# Convert HTML Template to Angular 16 - Menu Responsive doent work

Tags: html, angular, templates, bootstrap-5

I am converting a **html template** to **angular 16**, it work fine but when i tried the responsive menu, the menu (bars icon) appear but it doesnt work. I tried with other templates but i am having the same problem, maybe I am forgetting something?

The process I follow is:
1 ) copy all the folders (css, js, img, etc) from **html template** to **assets** folder In my angular project.
2 ) copy all the *link styles and script path* from **template index.html**  to  **angular index.html** file.
3 ) copy the **header from html template** to **app.component.html**

I run it , and work but when i reduce the resolution for test the responsive menu, the responsive menu work but when i click in the icon menu, it doesnt show the menu.

What is wrong in my process?

PS: i dont install bootstrap in the project, i mean, I dont use npm for install bootstrap, i just usint the css and js files from the html template.

Thanks

Comment: Generally all the templates that use javascript, wait to draw and execute one function (generally it's based in jQuery). In Angular you need change the angular.json to add this .js and call the function in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: ok I saw that in one example in internet. i will try that and I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: hi again, I test many things, installing jquery library for example.  Nothing work.  I create a blank project and i use only bootstrap (not external templates) , I tried the navbar and this work perfect in responsive mode.  But when I try the template header the boton menu for responsive doesnt work. I figure out the template use jquery library, i include it in the project (index.html and assets folder) but nothing happend

Comment: Yeah the javascript has to be implemented the "angular" way. Best bet is to use [this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), [this](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) or [this](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap#readme) library

Comment: Yes, I decided to use Bootstrap 5 and build the template from scratch :-(